# How to add id field to JsonObject using SORM in play framework on scala?

Tags: sorm

this is my case class:

```
case class Admin(name: String, surname: String, login: String, password: String
```

this is my json formatter:

```
implicit val adminWrite: Writes[Admin] = (
      (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "surname").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "login").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "password").write[String]
    )(unlift(Admin.unapply))
```

what i get:

```
{
name: "ddd",
surname: "ddd",
login: "djamik123",
password: "djamik123"
}
```

what i need:

```
{
id: 1,
name: "ddd",
surname: "ddd",
login: "djamik123",
password: "djamik123"
}
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?